# No Module named 'typing_extensions' 'from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient'

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, package

I have installed and uninstalled azure.storage.blob multiple times, but this error persist. I have also tried installing typing-extensions myself. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. As I can see, there weren't any updates to my existing code or the package itself. I did run pip list and typing_extensions was in there.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and reinstalling typing_extensions itself fixed my problem.